# Symfony2: validation constraint ignored when submitting form and with multiple validation groups

Tags: validation, symfony, assert

**Problem:**

The `Length` constraint is ignored when submitting my form.

**Entity:**

```
/**
 * @Assert\Length(min = "6")
 * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"registro"})
 */
private $password;
```

---

**FormType:**

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
    'data_class' => 'BikeApp\UsuariosBundle\Entity\Usuarios',
    'validation_groups' => array('default', 'registro')
    ));     
}
```

Comment: have you tried using a validation.yml instead of an assert?
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html
i have a feeling assert only works on when you save an entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the constant `Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint::DEFAULT_GROUP`, the default validation group is not `default` but `Default`.

Comment: Thanks, it resolve the problem. I changed                        'validation_groups' => array('default', 'registro')));               to                                                    'validation_groups' => array('Default', 'registro')));             And now it work.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason its not getting called from your entity so try adding the validation constraint in your `buildForm()`  method

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('nombre')
        ->add('apellidos')  
        ->add('email', 'email', array('label' => 'Correo electrónico', 'attr' => array(
            'placeholder' => 'usuario@servidor'
        )))
        ->add('password', 'repeated', array(
            'type' => 'password',
            'invalid_message' => 'Las dos contraseñas deben coincidir',
            'first_options'   => array('label' => 'Contraseña'),
            'second_options'  => array('label' => 'Repite Contraseña'),
            'required'        => true,
            'constraints'     =>array(new Assert\Length(array('min' => 6,'message'=>'La contraseña debe tener al menos {{ limit }} carácteres')))
            ))
        ->add('fechaNacimiento', 'birthday', array('required'=> false, 'widget' => 'single_text'))
        ->add('dni')
        ->add('newsletter', 'checkbox', array('required' => false));    
}
```

Don't forget to add use before your form class

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
```